# How to navigate to new activity by using two spinners and onclick submit button?

Tags: java, android

[activity_assessment.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KixN.png)

[assessment.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTJtE.png)

[assessment.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIHLR.png)
[arrays.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xYv7.png)

**Eventhough , i am clicking on submit button i am unable to move to another activity.**
**Can you please help me in this how to navigate to other new activity by using two spinners and a submit button?**
**Above i attached my source code files**

Comment: It'd better if you can post the code here instead of the photos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DON'T USE == in the if statement if(SpinnerValue1)

USE

```
.equals("TEST-1")
```

Like:

```
if(SpinnerValue1.equals("TEST-1"))
```

because SpinnerValue is an Object and you can't logically compare objects with "=="

[See this](https://www.javatpoint.com/string-comparison-in-java)

Also, I have this simple way of working with spinners :

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        //Instead of using getSelected(), use position 
        spinnerValue = position;
        //or
        useValueFrom(yourDataArrayAt[position]);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
});
```